# The relationship between matrix rank and its generalized inverse rank..

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let's say that $r=rank(A)$ where $A$ is a rectangular matrix, and $r'=rank(A^+)$ where $A^+$ is the generalized inverse of $A$.

[$A^+ = VS^+U^T$]

Is there any relationship between $r$ and $r'$? Like a specific equality or inequality? Or maybe a way to calculate $r'$ by knowing the value of $r$?

My guess was that they're equal but then based on the definition of $A^+$ we might have some zeroes after doing the multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because the $U$ and $V$ in the singular value decomposition are unitary ( hence invertible), we have
$rank(A) = rank(S) = rank(S^+) = rank(A^+)$.

Multiplying by invertible matrices on either side does not influence rank.

Comment: Why multiplying by invertible matrices doesn't change the rank? Thanks for helping with the question btw

Comment: The rank of $A$ is the dimension of the range of $A$, seen as a linear map between some $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$. Multiplying $A$ on the left means composing $A$ with an invertible operator on $\mathbb R^m$. The range of the composition still has dimension $r(A)$. (An invertible operator sends subspaces to subspaces of the same dimension.) Similarly for multiplication on the right, by viewing $A$ as a linear map between $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^n$.